# Изменения прав доступа на cifs-точку монтирования

Tags: linux, root, samba, raspbian

Есть ОС Raspbian. Есть смонтированный `mount.cifs` диск Windows10 в файловую /mnt/share/ Авторизация произведена под админом на диске.
Но при попытке редактирования файлов или добавления новых, стоит ограничение на права. 
В свойствах:
Владелец root
Группа root

`sudo chmod 777 /mnt/share` не помогает, доступ не предоставляется

```
stat -c '%A %a %n' /mnt/share
```

выводит:

```
drwxr-xr-x 755 /mnt/share
```

команда на изменения владельца папки также ни к чему не привела:

```
sudo chowm -R pi /mnt/share
```

Программой nautilus также ничего изменить не удалось.
Подскажите, проблема в моей ОС или все-таки доступ блокируется на удаленном смонтированном диске. и как ее можно решить. как поменять владельца

Comment: какие параметры монтирования? и удаётся ли изменять/создавать файлы от root'а?

Comment: sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.250/Share /mnt/share -o username=***,password=***
использовал:
cd /mnt/share/
sudo touch 'test.txt'
ничего к сожалению не создалось

Comment: Попробовал открыть текстовый файл sudo nano и редактировать, то данные изменились, но создать новый файл с помощью редактора nano не получилось

Comment: Команда sudo cat > text.txt
bash: text.txt: Отказано у доступе
тоесть это проблема со стороны дискового ресурса?

Comment: не используй голый sudo с перенаправлениями... `sudo cat > text.txt bash` — выполняет `cat` от root'а, а перенаправление от обычного пользователя поэтому и не работает...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко, то при монтировании удалённых *шар* (*share*) с не-POSIX-систем изменение владельца и атрибутов доступа не поддерживается cifs (см. Примечание). В таких случаях, подобно *сторонним* (*foreign*) ФС вроде NTFS или FAT, пользователя/группу, которые будут владельцем всех файлов, а также права доступа к файлам/каталогам необходимо задавать при монтировании.

А если говорить конкретно. то для этого есть опции `uid`/`gid` для задания владельца/группы, а также `file_mode`/`dir_mode` для задания прав на файлы/каталоги.

Так вместо

```
chowm -R pi /mnt/share
```

Стоило смонтировать с `-o uid=pi`

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.250/Share /mnt/share -o username=***,password=***,uid=pi
```

и т.п.; подробности см. в [`man mount.cifs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs)

**Примечание:** На самом деле возможно использовать права доступа из NTFS, но это относительно хитрое занятие.

Comment: большое спасибо! отличного Вам дня! все получилось